# What are the 9V battery terminal size specifications?

Tags: batteries, specifications, terminal

I'm trying to find the dimensions of a 9V (PP3?) battery (no specific chemistry). For some reason it's giving me a lot of trouble. I've been able to find most of the information (I checked a bunch of sources and they've all got these same values):

[image]

However, I can't figure out the allowable range for the terminal diameters and depths. So my question is, what are the min/max values of these dimensions:

[image]

Where:

- M = min/max outer diameter of positive male terminal
- F = min/max inner diameter of negative female terminal
- H = min/max depth of negative female terminal

The min/max height of the positive male terminal I assume is linked to the female depth and also the 0.1mm - 2.1mm minimum range implied (**A - D**) by the first image above.

Also, there's the lip on the terminals to provide the snap action, so, that too.

Comment: There's nothing crazy about the lower end of the A-D range. Many 9V batteries have the face with the contacts somewhat recessed below the edges of the metal shell (the metal shell overhangs the plastic piece carrying the contacts, just like on the battery in your picture). The 0.1 mm minimum just tells you that the contacts may be recessed as much to be almost flush with the metal shell.

Comment: @TooTea Ah, that makes a *lot* more sense.

Comment: For what it's worth, your "F" dimension across the corners of the hexagon is not very useful. It would be more useful to have the dimension between midpoints of opposite sides, as these are the points that engage the mating stud. Though in the standard posted in the answers, these dimensions are not actually specified and simply have to mate reliably with the stud.

Comment: @gwideman Oops; that was a blunder in my diagram!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They're specified in the relevant standards, such as IEC 60086-1, which are not free. Fortunately, our friends at the [Kenyan Bureau of Standards](http://www.puntofocal.gov.ar/notific_otros_miembros/ken269_t.pdf) published a public review copy of the standard:

[image]

The relevant size for the 9V battery is the "Minature".

The male post is of specified dimensions, the female merely has to fit the male (OC render).

### [image]

And, for completeness, here are the overall battery dimensions

[image]

If you are going to be signing off on tooling to make 1,000,000 snaps, it might be wise to double check against the actual latest standards, but as this battery design is >60 years old probably not much has changed other than conversion to metric.